# S3 Methods for Logical Operations

Tags: r

Let's say that I have an S3 object:

```
obj <- list()
obj$A <- "This"
obj$B <- "That"
class(obj) <- "myclass"
```

How would I go about writing a method for `myclass` such that it referenced `obj$B` (for example) when I called it to create a logical vector

For example, I would like this behaviour:

```
obj == "That" # TRUE 
obj == "This" # FALSE
```

I'd like `obj == "That"` to return `TRUE`, but how do I tell `==` which part of the object to test?

How do I find documentation for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should consider writing an `Ops.myclss` method. It gives you the ability to handle all group methods in a single function.

See `?base::Ops`, and `methods(Ops)` for example implementations. There's also a bit of information in [Section 5.6 - Group Methods](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Group-methods) of [R Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html).

Here's an example `Ops.myclass` that is a slightly modified version of `Ops.Date`:

```
Ops.myclass <-
function (e1, e2) 
{
    if (nargs() == 1) 
        stop(gettextf("unary %s not defined for \"myclass\" objects", 
            .Generic), domain = NA)
    boolean <- switch(.Generic, `<` = , `>` = , `==` = , `!=` = , 
        `<=` = , `>=` = TRUE, FALSE)
    if (!boolean) 
        stop(gettextf("%s not defined for \"myclass\" objects", 
            .Generic), domain = NA)
    if (inherits(e1, "myclass"))
        e1 <- e1$B
    if (inherits(e2, "myclass"))
        e2 <- e2$B
    NextMethod(.Generic)
}
```

Note that comparison will work whether or not `e1` or `e2` are `myclass` objects. And it will also work for any classes that extend `myclass` but do not define their own `Ops` method (though the error message would be confusing).

Comment: Interesting, so if I'm reading this correctly, it doesn't just cover the `==` scenario but rather all potential logical operators?

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen: Yes, and some math operators, as listed in the *Details* section of `?base::Ops`.

Answer (score 4):

What about :

```
`==.myclass` <- function(e1, e2){ e1$B == e2 }

> obj=="That"
[1] TRUE
> obj=="This"
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Where did you find documentation for `e1` and `e2`?

Comment: [There](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022979/operator-overloading-and-class-definition-in-r-use-a-different-base-field-corpu) but it's pretty outdated

Comment: HaHaHa. The syntax of base R might be "outdated" to some but it is relatively stable.