# Force R to print 0/0 as 1

Tags: r, math, arithmetic-expressions

When I execute `0 / 0` in R, I would get a `NaN` as an output. But is there any way I could print `0 / 0` as `1`? I know I could use some `if` statements to achieve it. I would like to know if there is any other way to achieve this.

Comment: Can you just replace your `NaN`s with `1`? `x[is.nan(x)] <- 1`?

Comment: See the answers to this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022979/operator-overloading-and-class-definition-in-r-use-a-different-base-field-corpu It describe how to overload math Ops.

Comment: An easier option would be to define a function, say, `div` and use it for division.

Comment: If this is about something like `sin(x)/x` at `x=0` then it would be better to have this continuation in the function definition, in C-like syntax `(1+x*x==1)?1:sin(x)/x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define your own division symbol especially for this. For example,

```
'|' <- function(a,b)ifelse(a==0 & b==0, 1, a/b)

> 0|0
[1] 1
> 3|4
[1] 0.75
```

Comment: If you prefer a more telling name, you can define an operator enclosed in `%`, as in `%div%`.  If efficiency is a concern, I would recommend `%div% <- function(a, b){ x <- a/b; x[is.nan(x)] <- 1; x}` (but the improvement in efficiency is very small)

Answer (score 0):

Other way than using `If` statement would be

```
# Assign NaN to vector
a <- 0 / 0
# If is NaN assign value 1
a[is.nan(a)] <- 1
```